# Android volley post request not working properly

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I have to make a POST request to a url using volley library. I've built the following custom classes for volley :-
**CustomJSONObjectRequest**

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by user on 4/14/2016.
 */

public class CustomJSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {
    Map<String, String> mParams;

    public CustomJSONObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                   Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        return mParams;
    }

    @Override
    public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
        // here you can write a custom retry policy

        return super.getRetryPolicy();
    }


}
```

**CustomVolleyRequestQueue**

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

/**
 * Created by Devastrix on 4/14/2016.
 */
public class CustomVolleyRequestQueue {

    private static CustomVolleyRequestQueue mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private CustomVolleyRequestQueue(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CustomVolleyRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(mCtx.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            // Don't forget to start the volley request queue
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

}
```

I'm using the following function to make POST request :-

```
RequestQueue mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context)
                .getRequestQueue();
        String url = "someURL";
       Log.d("URL= ", url);
        final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Log.d("post: ", response+"");

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   error.printStackTrace();


            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("A", "[[\"123\",\"456\",\"789\"]]"); // it is a json string actually
                params.put("B", "23-11-2016");
                params.put("C", "ABC");
                return params;
                //return query;
            }
        };
        jsonRequest.setTag(TAG);
        int socketTimeout = TIMEOUT;//30 seconds - 
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

But the problem is the request is returning null data whereas when I'm using some third party app for POST request it returns the correct result. What might be the possible bug?

**EDIT** - Actually the response is not null. The true response is like this.

```
{
  "data" : ""
}
```

But the data key shouldn't have empty value.SO i think there is either problem with the params or the params are not getting sent properly. But the params are totaly correct i've checked.

Comment: What data do you expect the server to return in response to a successful (2xx) POST? Also, what format should that data be in? JSON?

Comment: The data is in JSON format. The key 'data' should contain some JSONObject but the response shows 'data' key to have empty key.

Comment: I see. The only thing I can think of is that the server really is returning nothing for the `data` attribute. Try adding logging on the server side so that you can see exactly what the server is packing into `data` when it builds its response. Or, on the app side, intercept the raw response before the data within it gets converted to a `JSONObject`, and check its contents. You should be able to do this by overriding `protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {` and using the debugger or logging.

Comment: i am also facing same issue, volley returning me empty string " ", dont know why. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please add this dependency to your project's build.gradle method.
after this add your parameter which you want to send to server.

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

now add this activity on your project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  ProgressDialog progress_dialog;
    private RequestQueue queue;
    private HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        GetEventCodeResponse("d@gmail.com","4");

    }
    public void GetEventCodeResponse(String email,String event){
        progress_dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress_dialog.setMessage("Getting data, please wait a moment...");
        progress_dialog.show();
        map.put("username", email);
        map.put("eventcode", event);
        getResponseFromServer("your own url",map);
    }
    public void getResponseFromServer(String url, final HashMap<String, String> map) {
        System.out.println("url----"+url);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("response reviw--",response);
                        progress_dialog.dismiss();
                       /* rating();*/
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        try{
                            Log.e("sign error password", new String(error.networkResponse.data));

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        progress_dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return map;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                100000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    }
}
```

Comment: not working...this code is actually similar to  mine

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, the request is definitely succeeding and the `onResponse(JSONObject response)` method of the `Response.Listener<JSONObject>` instance you're providing to the request is being called with response being `null`?

Also, is there Volley related showing up in logcat?

**Update in response to comments**

My feeling is that we still haven't locked down a definite root cause for the issue you're seeing, so I can't guarantee that the following code will resolve it. As you asked, though, please try the following:

```
RequestQueue mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();
String url = "someURL";
Log.d("URL= ", url);

final JSONObject requestBody;
try {
    requestBody = new JSONObject();
    requestBody.put("A", new JSONArray(new String[]{ "123", "456", "789" });
    requestBody.put("B", "23-11-2016");
    requestBody.put("C", "ABC");
} catch (JSONException exception) {
    // error handling which, at least in theory, shouldn't be needed ...
}

final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.d("post: ", response+"");

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               error.printStackTrace();


        }
    });

jsonRequest.setTag(TAG);
int socketTimeout = TIMEOUT;//30 seconds - 
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

Comment: Yes response is generated but it is null. No i'm not using Volley logcat

Comment: That's strange ... `JsonObjectRequest` creates a new `JSONObject` upon success, and throws an exception if it can't then parse the response body data, so I would have expected the `response` object provided via the `onResponse` method to never be `null`? Sorry I wasn't able to help ... I'll keep thinking about it!

Comment: Actually the response is not null. The true response is a key value pair in which the value is returned as empty string. SO i think there is either problem with the params or the params are not getting sent properly. But the params are totaly correct i've checked.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If so, you could check the logs and perhaps the data being stored (if any) as a result of the POST. Also, if you're POSTing a JSON object in the body of the request, it might be easier to provide the data via the `JSONObject jsonRequest` parameter of the request constructor. This will take care of encoding and so on for you, which is one less thing to worry about (compared to sending string representations of JSON arrays, say).

Comment: Ok. Can u just write it in the form of code what u said about the JSON parameter?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. Be aware that it may not resolve your issue, though. Checking the server (logs and data) would be a good next step.

Comment: No, this is also not working. But thanks for the answer.